# setState triggers infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling

I am trying to rerender component after retrieving data from the backend on page load with axios as well as clicking the `Enter course name` button in the form. So far I am able to rerender after the page has loaded using setState for isLoading. However, when I try to rerender on button click for courseList by using `setCourseList()` in `handleClick`, it seems to trigger an infinite loop of re-rendering. I don't know what is causing the issue... Is it using `setCourseList` in an event handler? If so, how can I avoid infinite rerendering?

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
//import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


function Course() {
    //const navigate = useNavigate();s
    
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(true);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const [data, setData] = useState({
        email: cookies.get('email'),
        addName: '',
      });
    
    const [courseList, setCourseList] = useState([]);
    axios
    .post('http://localhost:8000/api/course', data)
    .then((res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setCourseList(res.data.course);
        console.log(res.data.course);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });

    function handleInput(e) {
        const newData={...data};
        newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
        setData(newData);
    }

    function handleClick() {
        setShowResults(false);
        setLoading(true);
        console.log(data.addName);
        axios
        .post('http://localhost:8000/api/add-course', data)
        .then((res) => {
            setCourseList(res.data.course);
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }
    if (isLoading) {
        return (<body>
            <div className="Loading">
            <h2>Loading...</h2>
            </div>
            </body>);
    }

    return ( 
        <div id="course_page" className="course_page">
         <body>
            <h2 id="title">Course</h2>
            <div className="form1" id="form1">
            { courseList ? <form>
                {courseList.map(course => (
                    <Link className="btn" to="/Start"> 
                    <input id={course.courseName} class={course.courseName} type="submit" value={course.courseName}/> 
                    </Link>
            ))}
            </form> : null }
            { showResults ? <form onSubmit={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)} className="addName" name="addName" value={data.addName} id="addName" placeholder="Enter course name"/> 
                <input id="addCourse" className="addCourse" type="submit" value="Add Course"/> 
            </form> : null }
           
            </div>
            </body>
        </div>
      );
}

export default Course;
```

Comment: Use an effect. Do not make an http request every time the component is rendered!

Comment: You need to wrap your axios request in a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array. At the moment you're getting the data, setting state which causes a new render, which means you get the data again, and update the state etc.

Comment: I wrapped with `useEffect` and it did stop the infinite rendering, however, it doesn't re-render when I click the button. I tried to pass courseList to the dependency array but it shows a blank page. Any idea why this is happening? I thought it will update after I setState in event handler.